# Set line spacing everywhere but in verbatim blocks

Tags: verbatim, line-spacing, setspace

Is it possible to change the linespacing of a document except for inside verbatim blocks?

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
```

The above results in more readable paragraphs, but the code snippets are too large for my taste.

Answer (score 6):

Just patch `\verbatim@font` or (even safer) `\verbatim` macro to add your code before verbatim blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\verbatim{\singlespacing}
\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{verbatim}
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("Hello world.");
    return 0;
}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, if you use `fancyvrb` package for verbatim, you could use `\fvset` to set `formatcom` option for all `Verbatim` (not `verbatim`) environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{formatcom=\singlespacing}
\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{Verbatim}
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("Hello world.");
    return 0;
}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```